# DataStax Lifecycle Manager Failing to Install New Cluster

Tags: datastax, opscenter

We are using Lifecycle Manager to distribute DSE to a new Cass cluster.  The install fails no matter what is tried.  The log shows the following where I edited ip addresses.

> Meld failed on name="node1_name" ssh-management-address="node1_ip" node-id="37292a99-f324-4967-803c-d9c50ab0b87b" job-id="d413b5ba-ba87-4de4-bac7-2efac334d2d4" stdout="503 Server Error: Connect failed for url: http://opscenter:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/37292a99-f324-4967-803c-d9c50ab0b87b/status event-resource=http://opscenter:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/37292a99-f324-4967-803c-d9c50ab0b87b/status2017-07-10 15:53:43,925 - opsc-meld - ERROR - 503 Server Error: Connect failed for url: http://opscenter:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/37292a99-f324-4967-803c-d9c50ab0b87b/status event-resource=http://opscenter:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/37292a99-f324-4967-803c-d9c50ab0b87b/status " stderr=""

Comment: LCM developer here. Are there other errors in the opscenter log just before that message?  http://opscenter:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/37292a99-f324-4967-803c-d9c50ab0b87b/status is the endpoint we use to post status updates from the target-node to the server during jobs. A 5xx response code means that the server (or something impersonating the server) received the update but was unable to process it. If the message reached the LCM server, it should have logged why it was unable to process the message. If there is no additional error... do you have a network device that might issue a 5xx?

Comment: Here is the full log where it appears it is to download the definition and fails.  I just checked that ports are open between opscenter node and cass nodes.  

INFO: Trying to establish ssh connection ssh-management-address="node1_ipaddress" node-name="node1_name" node-id="37292a99-f324-4967-803c-d9c50ab0b87b" job-id="d413b5ba-ba87-4de4-bac7-2efac334d2d4" (async-thread-macro-1)
2017-07-10 15:52:45,317 [opscenterd]  WARN: Trying to download definition file hash ht tps://opscenter.datastax.com:443/definitions/6.1.1/version.md5 resulted in following error: Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: File "/usr/share/opscenter/jython/Lib/site-packages/opscenterd/Definitions.py", line 382, in getNewHash
TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure.
 (MainThread)

Comment: Then the log shows the meld error I previously posted followed by:
ERROR: Install job d413b5ba-ba87-4de4-bac7-2efac334d2d4 failed! (async-thread-macro-1)
2017-07-10 16:52:45,212 [opscenterd]  WARN: Trying to download definition file hash ht tps://opscenter.datastax.com:443/definitions/6.1.1/version.md5 resulted in following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/jython/Lib/site-packages/opscenterd/Definitions.py", line 382, in getNewHash
TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure.

Comment: The definitions errors are a red-herring, they're happening because tour OpsC node doesn't have outbound internet access. They can be disabled by disabling definitions auto-update per https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opscenter/opsc/configure/opscConfigProps_r.html#opscConfigProps__definitions-auto_update.

Comment: As to your real problem... I've never seen it before. I'm guessing you have a network device between your target and your lcm server that's preventing http requests from getting through and giving you a confusing 5xx error. You can verify that LCM is not receiving the request by setting <logger name="lcm" level="TRACE"/> in opscenter's logback.xml, restarting OpsCenter (you should now see a lot message for each API request sent to LCM when you click around the UI). Rerun your job and look for a POST to that URL. If you don't see one, you'll need to troubleshoot your network.

Comment: Also, consider joining https://academy.datastax.com/slack or pinging your sales rep if you're in the startup program. Debugging environmental problems without a private communication channel is often painful because the relevant info all has to be redacted.

Comment: Worked through proxy issues and now the error is the following:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='debian.datastax.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /enterprise (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fede0ac4090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

What is I do not understand is that the log shows that get apt-get will be used and that access is ok when I test but the above error is triggered.  

Thanks for your guidance above through this struggle.

Comment: apt-get (or yum as appropriate) is used to download the packages themselves, but it's not the only component that needs outbound network access. Rather than manually configuring your apt proxy outside of LCM, you need to set the proxy in the proxy-tab of your LCM config-profile and then LCM will use that proxy configuration for all components that need outbound internet.

Comment: See this kbase for details: https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/213304303-Lifecycle-Manager-Offline-Installation-of-DSE

Comment: After a few config changes here is the error:
"stderr": "W: The repository 'http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise stable Release' does not have a Release file.\nE: Failed to fetch http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  400  Invalid header received from client\nE: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.\nW: Duplicate sources.list entry http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise stable Release",
  "return_code": 100

Comment: The error-message here seems relatively clear. You've manually set up the debian.datastax.com repository in apt, resulting in duplicate apt-entries. Manual repo setup is neither necessary nor wise because LCM configures the repository based on the settings you specified in the the LCM UI. Possibly because of that problem, apt is having outbound network problems with your proxy. At this point you need to post your specific repo configs and proxy configs (redacted of hostnames/uesrnames/passwords) and you may need to drop down to tcpdump to figure out what your proxy is doing.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback over the past 2 days.  There is no need to move forward.